# Javascript variables in css are not working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, web-deployment, react-fullstack

In this code i am passing both imageurl and size which are javascript variables but i am using in css.
css is not considering both. How to resolve this issue ??

```
const MenuItem = ({title, imageUrl, size}) => {
    return(
        <div className="${size} menu-item">
            <div className="background-image" style={{backgroundImage: "url(${imageUrl})"}} />
            <div className="content">
                <h1 className="title">{title.toUpperCase()}</h1>
                <span className="subtitle">SHOP NOW</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: do you see the size class inside your HTML? or `menu-item` is all you see?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
const MenuItem = ({title, imageUrl, size}) => {
return(
    <div className={`${size} menu-item`}>
        <div className="background-image" style={{backgroundImage: "url(${imageUrl})"}} />
        <div className="content">
            <h1 className="title">{title.toUpperCase()}</h1>
            <span className="subtitle">SHOP NOW</span>
        </div>
    </div>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use variables inside a string like this, you need to use the following syntax:

```
className={`${size} menu-item`}
```

Comment: single quotation marks instead of double quotation marks ??

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap them in back-ticks (``` `` ```):

```
const MenuItem = ({title, imageUrl, size}) => {
    return(
        <div className=`${size} menu-item`>
            <div className="background-image" style={{backgroundImage: `${url(${imageUrl})}`}} />
            <div className="content">
                <h1 className="title">{title.toUpperCase()}</h1>
                <span className="subtitle">SHOP NOW</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    );

}
```